# Ble advertisement Data slow interval time

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Currently I am sending advertisement data from a BLE device to my iOS app and printing their values. At the beginning I was able to print each advertisement data but after some time, it seems that the didDiscoverPeripheral method used in printing the incoming packets is no longer called consistently and the interval of time increased since the app has started.

Any reason for that?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Since I am receiving advertisement data from a BLE device without connecting to it, the following is not being called:

> NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
>
> [_manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];

The above code will get didDiscoverPeripheral" callback with every advertisement packet that is being send by the device to the IPhone.

Hope that helps!